# Question on tuning file system cache in Linux UBIFS on MTD

Tags: linux, filesystems, cache, block-device, ubifs

I am working on an embedded Linux system, where kernel is 5.10.24, and UBIFS on MTD is used.

The testing team had a test, which writes a disk file (`open`, `write`, `close` in order), then powers system off.  After power on, the disk file is empty, no data is really written. It is found that after file writing, delay about 1 min, then power cycle the system, the file is updated!

I did some study and had followings.

1. The ubifs creates a kernel thread `ubifs_bgt0_0`, which will be scheduled every ~30seconds. It will write buffer to block layer (Maybe I am wrong).
2. The `ubifs_bgt0_0` creates timer for wbuf, the timer's period is set to `dirty_write_interval`, it is defined as `unsigned int dirty_writeback_interval = 5 * 100; /* centiseconds */`, about 5seconds. This does NOT match the 1 min delay reported by testing team.
3. The `/sys/block/mtdblock0/queue/scheduler` is `[mq-deadline]`, and `/sys/block/mtdblock0/queue/iosched/write_expire` is 5000, 5 seconds.

With above findings, I think the file writing in UBIFS will be written to FLASH in 5 seconds.  Power cycle before that time will cause data lost!!

So please firstly correct me on above analysis.

Then, I want to verify my analysis by changing the tunables listed in `2` and `3`.
I changed them as follows,
`echo 100 > /proc/sys/vm/dirty_writeback_centisecs` and `echo 1000 > /sys/block/mtdblock2/queue/iosched/write_expire`.  I want to descrease the FLASH writing from 50 seconds to 1 second.

With above changes, I ran the disk writing tests, and power cycle system in 2 seconds. But to my surprise, the file is NOT written correctly！

I tried many times by changing above 2 parameters to different values (less than 50 seconds), but I still failed to make data written to FLASH if the system is power cycled in 50 seconds.

I used Ftrace to check the functions called in file writing after `echo 100 /proc/sys/vm/dirty_writeback_centisecs`.

Here is the Ftrace for about 10 seconds (after file writing)

```
######### 10 centiseconds

# CPU  DURATION                  FUNCTION CALLS
# |     |   |                     |   |   |   |
 1)               |  ubifs_write_iter() {
 1) + 18.334 us   |    ubifs_write_begin();
 1) + 10.833 us   |    ubifs_write_end();
 1) + 62.167 us   |  }
 ------------------------------------------
 1)    exe-399     =>   ubifs_b-72
 ------------------------------------------

 1)               |  mtd_write() {
 1)               |    mtd_write_oob() {
 1)               |      mtd_write_oob_std() {
 1)               |        emu_nand_write_oob() {
 1) ! 491.167 us  |          nand_do_write();
 1) ! 502.000 us  |        }
 1) ! 507.167 us  |      }
 1) ! 512.667 us  |    }
 1) ! 525.667 us  |  }
```

The disk file is NOT written after power cycle.

Here is the function trace I got for 60 seconds after file writing.

```
# tracer: function_graph
#
# CPU  DURATION                  FUNCTION CALLS
# |     |   |                     |   |   |   |
 1)               |  ubifs_write_iter() {
 1) + 20.000 us   |    ubifs_write_begin();
 1)   9.000 us    |    ubifs_write_end();
 1) + 59.166 us   |  }
 ------------------------------------------
 1)    exe-924     =>   kworker-61
 ------------------------------------------

 1)               |  ubifs_writepage() {
 1) + 49.500 us   |    ubifs_write_inode();
 1) ! 110.000 us  |  }
 1)   3.833 us    |  ubifs_write_inode();
 0)               |  mtd_write() {
 0)               |    mtd_write_oob() {
 0)               |      mtd_write_oob_std() {
 0)               |        emu_nand_write_oob() {
 0) ! 477.666 us  |          nand_do_write();
 0) ! 489.000 us  |        }
 0) ! 493.833 us  |      }
 0) ! 500.000 us  |    }
 0) ! 516.500 us  |  }
 0)               |  mtd_write() {
 0)               |    mtd_write_oob() {
 0)               |      mtd_write_oob_std() {
 0)               |        emu_nand_write_oob() {
 0) ! 459.333 us  |          nand_do_write();
 0) ! 465.667 us  |        }
 0) ! 470.000 us  |      }
 0) ! 474.666 us  |    }
 0) ! 481.500 us  |  }
 1) + 54.333 us   |  ubifs_write_inode();
 1) + 26.000 us   |  ubifs_write_inode();
 1) + 20.666 us   |  ubifs_write_inode();
 1) + 19.834 us   |  ubifs_write_inode();
 1) + 14.000 us   |  ubifs_write_inode();
 1) + 13.667 us   |  ubifs_write_inode();
 1) + 11.500 us   |  ubifs_write_inode();
 1) + 14.333 us   |  ubifs_write_inode();
 0)               |  mtd_write() {
 0)               |    mtd_write_oob() {
 0)               |      mtd_write_oob_std() {
 0)               |        emu_nand_write_oob() {
 0) ! 471.167 us  |          nand_do_write();
 0) ! 481.167 us  |        }
 0) ! 486.500 us  |      }
 0) ! 492.167 us  |    }
 0) ! 506.166 us  |  }
#
```

The disk file is written correctly after power cycle.

The Ftrace difference seemed to be about `inode`, but I am not sure if there is tunable for it or not!

So I must miss something important when I try to tune this UBIFS file writing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the turning-knob to make file writing work *instantly* to FLASH storage.

I missed another parameter just defined below `dirty_writeback_interval`, it is `unsigned int dirty_expire_interval = 30 * 100; /* centiseconds */`.

By setting it and `dirty_writeback_centisecs` to `100` (1 second), power cycle the system 1 second after file writing can make file is updated correctly.

I need to read more on these paramters, so far I am still not clear why `dirty_expire_centisecs` is critical, does it launch another timer to flush dirty data???